# First ng-repeat boolean true, rest false

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.5. I have a li element with a ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="contract in vm.contracts.items" contract="contract" change-payment-method-active="vm.changePaymentMethodSssIsActive">
    <contract-timeline-item></contract-timeline-item>
</li>
```

Inside the li element is an `contract-timeline-item` component.

Each `contract-timeline-item` component his this html:

```
<div id="toggleContract"><button ng-click="vm.toggleContract()">Toggle contract</button></div>
<div class="uc-card-datablock" ng-if="vm.toggle">
```

And this code:

```
private toggle: boolean = false;

public toggleContract() {
    this.toggle = (this.toggle === true) ? false : true;
}
```

When a user opens the page the toggle boolean value for all contracts is false and users can click the toggle button to open/close them.

But I would like the toggle value to be true for the first contract so it's visible to the users.

I could solve this by adding a `toggleStatus` value to the contract model and in the parent container I could take the first contract item of the contracts array and set  the `toggleStatus` to true. But I was hoping to do this without changing the model and adding properties that don't belong in that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are after you need to use component the way they are supposed to be used, i.e. pass data in via bindings. You will pass your contract data and as well as the flag to tell weather you deal with `contract-timeline-item` which is the first or not.

It will look something like this:

```
class contractTimelineItem {
    private toggle: boolean = false;

    $onInit() {
      this.toggle = this.expanded;
    }

    public toggleContract() {
      this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    }    
  }
```

where bindings for this component would look like this:

```
bindings: {
  contract: '=',
  expanded: '<'
},
```

Then HTML part would need to be this:

```
<li ng-repeat="contract in vm.contracts.items" contract="contract" change-payment-method-active="vm.changePaymentMethodSssIsActive">
  <contract-timeline-item 
    expanded="$first"
    contract="contract"
  ></contract-timeline-item>
</li>
```

Here is a **demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/9v8xdl7YR4oBYt3Bjgf3?p=preview

Comment: Cheers! Was just looking at this. This works much easier in Angular 2, but for now I'm stuck in 1.5.

Comment: I do have to add `private expanded: boolean;` to my class otherwise I get the `TS2339: Property 'expanded' does not exist on type` error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $index inside your ng-if to set toggle of first item to true

```
<div class="uc-card-datablock" ng-if="vm.toggle || $index == 0">
```

Comment: Hm this only works on the ng-repeat item. I guess I should rephrase my question. Each `contract-timeline-item` has a boolean toggleValue (boolean). And they are set to false, only the first should be true. So it's not so much about showing/hiding but passing a value to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $first in ng-repeat. This value will be true if it's the first element in the loop adding it as a parameter for your component.

```
<li ng-repeat="contract in vm.contracts.items" contract="contract" change-payment-method-active="vm.changePaymentMethodSssIsActive">
<contract-timeline-item toggle='$first'></contract-timeline-item>
```

Comment: What should I do with the `canBeToggled` ?

Comment: Just call it 'toggle', instead, my bad. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have separate directive scope, you will have to pass that which element is first, you can do it like this

```
<li ng-repeat="contract in vm.contracts.items" contract="contract" change-payment-method-active="vm.changePaymentMethodSssIsActive">
    <contract-timeline-item is-first="$first"></contract-timeline-item>
</li>
```

Now to use this in your scope code, do this -

```
private toggle: boolean = attr.isFirst;

public toggleContract() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
}
```

Comment: You think in right direction but this won't work. Plus it will throw syntax error.

Comment: attr.is-first will be true only for first element and false for rest, so toggle boolean is set right, then on toggleContract you just have to set the opposite value. I don't see why it won't work?

Comment: And where do you think `attr` will come from? ReferenceError will be throws because you didn't define variable `first` before using it.

Comment: attr is passed as parameter in link function of that directive, return{link: function(scope, element, attr) { //the directive scope code here}}. I guess that if person has made a directive then he has basic understanding of using attributes that can be passed to directive

Comment: Sure, but there are not link function and no directive in OP case :) try to create a demo with your code (don't forget typescript) and you will see what I mean.

Comment: `cannot find name attr Did you mean Attr`. That's the error I'm getting now.

Comment: @dfsq ok, I get it, I was assuming the normal angular js behavior without tyoescript

Comment: Yes, i know. And about ReferenceError: when you write `attr.is-first;` it means `attr.is` *minus* first. And since there is no first variable it will throw error. You want camel case notation `attrs.isFirst`.